# Rails scope for IS NOT NULL and is not empty/blank?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scope

I have the following scope:

```
scope :comments, :conditions => ['text_value IS NOT NULL']
```

But I also want the conditions to say "OR text_value IS NOT EMPTY" (or something to that effect).

I don't want to select any rows where `text_value` is empty/blank.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As Erwin points out, a simple `text_value <> ''` comparison will work in this case.

```
scope :comments, where("text_value <> ''")
```

(Rails 3 prefers this query syntax for `scope`—as well as `find`, `all`, etc.—rather than an options hash e.g. `:conditions => ...`. The latter is [deprecated in Rails 3.1](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface).)

In Rails 4, the second argument should be a lambda instead:

```
scope :comments, ->{ where("text_value <> ''") }
```

Comment: The `COALESCE()` is just cruft in this case, because `NULL <> ''` yields `NULL`. Only `TRUE` conditions qualify a row.

Comment: What about -- scope :comments, where("NOT text_value IS NULL")

Comment: In Rails 5 I would do `where.not(text_value: [nil, ""])`

Answer (score 61):

In Rails 4 you can do

```
where.not(text_value: '')
```

Comment: The beautiful solution.

Comment: Definitely the best answer for Rails 4 and up

Comment: won't this return rows where text_value is nil?

Comment: No, under the hood ActiveRecord will generate the same SQL as most other answers here (`text_value <> ''`). Admittedly, this is a bit of SQL magic...

Comment: @PatrickOscity although, that's kind of the idea behind using an ORM in the first place.

Comment: This seems to generate `!= ''` in rails 5 with mysql. However, since this still excludes null values, it's fine.

Comment: I believe `!=` is just an alias for `<>` in Postgres, so it should be fine there, too.

Answer (score 32):

rails 4

```
scope :comments, -> { where.not(:text_value => nil) }
```

Comment: This does *not* work as the original question requests.

Comment: Agree with @Backo but to clarify, this doesn't filter out the blanks, only nils.

Answer (score 9):

Use `text_value <> ''` to efficiently cover **both** cases.

Will only be `TRUE` for a `text_value` that is neither `NULL` nor `empty`.

Answer (score 3):

```
scope :comments, where("text_value <> ''")
```

Comment: `OR` is the wrong operator. This would accept an empty `text_value`.

Comment: yeah, empty text_value is also NOT NULL ;) - it's now corrected, thanks

Comment: Now it's correct. But you don't need the additional test `text_value IS NOT NULL`. See my answer and other comment. Operators `<>` and `!=` are identical for character types (and most other types as well).

Comment: I see it now - it's interesting and very useful. Thank you, sir

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am doing like this:

1) Add to initializers

```
class Arel::Attributes::Attribute
  # Encode column name like: `posts`.`author_id`
  def to_sql
    "`#{relation.table_name}`.`#{name}`"
  end

  def is_not_empty
    "#{to_sql} <> ''"
  end
end
```

2) Add to your model

```
scope :comments, -> { where(arel_table[:text_value].is_not_empty) }
```

Good luck!