# Ignore missing images of loop and display present ones - Rails 5 Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a carousel taking images from a has_one attached (marketing_image) Active Storage file upload method. I would like the carousel to still display if a marketing image is not uploaded.

Obviously I will need to have at least one for the carousel to work but I would like to find a way to skip over any missing images in the array and display only the ones that have been uploaded. I am using Rails 5. Thanks

I have tried the following but they hide the entire carousel, which is not what I want.

unless (product.marketing_image != nil?)

unless !product.marketing_image.blank?

Model

```
has_one_attached :product_image
has_one_attached :marketing_image
```

Show

```
 <%= image_tag product.marketing_image.variant(combine_options: {resize: '1000x450^', gravity: 'center', extent: '1000x450^'}), class: 'img-fluid'%>
```

Controller

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to find any marketing images from selected products? You could create a scope to find associated images that are not blank:

```
scope :with_marketing_images, -> { joins(:marketing_image).where.not(marketing_image.url: '') }
```

Then your carousel can be:

```
@marketing_images = @products.with_marketing_images
```

Also see [Rails scope for IS NOT NULL and is not empty/blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620547/rails-scope-for-is-not-null-and-is-not-empty-blank)